# IMAP to POP3 proxy

Tags: email, proxy, imap, pop3

We want to migrate our mail server to another one which only supports IMAP. We have a hard requirement to continue using our current email client which only supports POP3.

Is there any way to workaround this issue?

We have looked for some proxy but we haven't found any.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: I've seen such proxies, 20-25 years ago. They were rather painful: POP3 doesn't support folders, so all the mail had to remain in the inbox forever, which grows more painful with every passing year.  Look on github, I'm sure you can find something.

Comment: Theoretically, it wouldn't be that difficult to make.  POP3 is pretty much strictly a subset of IMAP (no folders, no flags), so any command POP3 can run can be translated into an IMAP command.  Alternatively, if you have a spare unix server, you could probably use something like imapsync to sync to a local mailbox, then stand up a POP3 server on that.

Comment: @Max, I didn't find any.